# Ubuntu 14.04 - Dual Monitor Issue (Aspect Ratio)

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, resolution, display

So I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I've been able to google every problem I had and find an answer except this one.

In screen display I can run my Built-in Display at 1366X768 (16:9) and my TV up to 1920 X 1080 (16:9) if they are extended. If I try to mirror the displays at 1366X768 (16:9) it limits the options to 4:3 and stretches the display.

Anyone have this issue before and/or find a situation?

Here's the display information I get from:

### sudo lshw -C video

> *-display
>
> > ```
> >   description: VGA compatible controller
> >    product: Sumo [Radeon HD 6480G]
> >    vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
> >    physical id: 1
> >    bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
> >    version: 00
> >    width: 32 bits
> >    clock: 33MHz
> >    capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
> >    configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
> >    resources: irq:44 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f053ffff
> > ```

Lastly I should mention I'm able to Mirror the displays in windows 7 so I doubt it is a hardware issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here. Did you find any solution, JoeyPhillips?

Comment: I had to install the Catalyst Control Center, which gave me more video options.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Install  AMD Catalyst Control Center - (Catalyst Control Center for the AMD graphics accelerators) fglrx-amdcccle

Worked with my Radeon HD 6480G